# My Wordpress Web site is Slow

Tags: wordpress, performance

Hello are there any plugins that can me speed up my wordpress site. Pleasei tried Wp Cache put it mess up my database please help

Answer (score 1):

First check you page speed and problems [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

> You can follow the mentions in the above link
>   Compress the images as possible
>   Minify the [CSS](https://cssminifier.com/)
>   Compress you [JavaScript](http://jscompress.com/)
>   Do not use too much database load in same page.

Thanks hope this will you.!